# Simplification of trig function composition?

Tags: trigonometry

I was wondering if there was any way to simplify thing like sin(cos(x)), cos(sin(x)), sin(tan(x)), etc. for non-inverse functions. Maybe even things like sin(sin(x)). This is just me wanting to know out of mathematical curiosity. Thanks.

Comment: As I said, non-inverse functions, so no. Already looked at that.

Comment: There is no simplification for any of the four functions you have written down.

Comment: ;( Ok, thanks...